# Replace with wildcards

Tags: c#, regex

I need some advice. Suppose I have the following string: `Read Variable`
I want to find all pieces of text like this in a string and make all of them like the following:`Variable = MessageBox.Show`. So as aditional examples:

```
"Read Dog" --> "Dog = MessageBox.Show"
"Read Cat" --> "Cat = MessageBox.Show"
```

Can you help me? I need a fast advice using RegEx in C#. I think it is a job involving wildcards, but I do not know how to use them very well... Also, I need this for a school project tomorrow... Thanks!

Edit: This is what I have done so far and it does not work: `Regex.Replace(String, "Read ", " = Messagebox.Show")`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. here it is what I have done: Regex.Replace(String, "Read *", "* = Messagebox.Show").

Comment: @m.buettner : I've found what I was looking for with this question (regex is a nightmare, I want ready-cooked answers, like most people). Please, don't ask people to find regex by themselves !! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this

```
string ns= Regex.Replace(yourString,"Read\s+(.*?)(?:\s|$)","$1 = MessageBox.Show");
```

`\s+` matches 1 to many space characters

`(.*?)(?:\s|$)` matches 0 to many characters till the first space (i.e `\s`) or till the end of the string is reached(i.e `$`)

`$1` represents the first captured group i.e `(.*?)`

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thank you! Can you explain it for me, please? I shall accept the answer in 8 minutes (stackoverflow told me I have to wait...)

Comment: Thanks! Wait 2 more minutes :)

Comment: You should note that this removes the trailing space if there is one. You probably wanted to use a lookahead instead `(?=\s|$)` or `(?!\S)`

Comment: @m.buettner i guess he doesn't want trailing white space

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It no, your regex includes the space in the match if it is there. thus, it will also be removed. if you use a lookahead, it will not be part of the match and will remain in the string.

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It or he didn't notice ;). it is certainly an effect of your solution that wasn't requested in the question, so I think it is fair to include a notice on that behavior in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to clarify your question... but here goes:

If you want to match the next word after "Read " in regex, use `Read (\w*)` where `\w` is the word character class and `*` is the greedy match operator.

If you want to match everything after "Read " in regex, use `Read (.*)$` where `.` will match all characters and `$` means end of line.

With either regex, you can use a replace of `$1 = MessageBox.Show` as $1 will reference the first matched group (which was denoted by the parenthesis).

Complete code:

```
replacedString = Regex.Replace(inStr, @"Read (.*)$", "$1 = MessageBox.Show");
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarification. I did not know about the $1. That is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your attempt is, that it cannot know that the replacement string should be inserted after your variable. Let's assume that valid variable names contain letters, digits and underscores (which can be conveniently matched with `\w`). That means, any other character ends the variable name. Then you could match the variable name, capture it (using parentheses) and put it in the replacement string with `$1`:

```
output = Regex.Replace(input, @"Read\s+(\w+)", "$1 = MessageBox.Show");
```

Note that `\s+` matches one or more arbitrary whitespace characters. `\w+` matches one or more letters, digits and underscores. If you want to restrict variable names to letters only, this is the place to change it:

```
output = Regex.Replace(input, @"Read\s+([a-zA-Z]+)", "$1 = MessageBox.Show");
```

[Here is a good tutorial.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Finally note, that in C# it is advisable to write regular expressions as verbatim strings (`@"..."`). Otherwise, you will have to double escape everything, so that the backslashes get through to the regex engine, and that really lessens the readability of the regex.

Comment: I already got the answer. But thanks for your advice regarding the use of verbatim strings. It helps a lot!

Comment: @ValentinRadu Well yeah, Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It was half a minute fast than I was, but having typed up all the explanation, I didn't want to throw the answer away ;).

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I have a lot of examples to do, so I shall definitely use you tips too and I shan't have to ask another question. Thanks!