# Finding a string in a string in C# with any char at some points

Tags: c#, string, character, any

I couldn't figure out the best way to explain this, but how would one go about doing something like `text.Replace("1*6", "hello")`?

Where **`*`** represents a **character/number** that can be anything, so that `"116"`, `"126"`, `"1e6"` etc would all be treated the same way and get replaced with `"hello"`.

Comment: you mean, like a regular expression?

Comment: you want like 1*6 then 1hello6 as output ?

Comment: Look into [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I guess so, but the * represents only one character that can be anything, not multiple ones

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace with wildcards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442855/replace-with-wildcards)

Comment: No the output would be as I said above, "1*ANY ONE CHARACTER HERE*6" is replaced by "hello" but anything else is left alone.
And thanks, Yuriy, I'll have a look there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work for you:

```
var text = "This is 1x6 in a string.";

var result = Regex.Replace(text, "1.6", "hello");
```

This gives me the result of:

> This is hello in a string.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex:

```
string input = "126";    
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "1.6", "hello");
```

More about regex:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use regex to replace

```
static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Regular expression built for C# on: Thu, Jul 3, 2014, 02:47:43 PM
        ///  Using Expresso Version: 3.0.4750, http://www.ultrapico.com
        ///  
        ///  A description of the regular expression:
        ///  
        ///  1.6
        ///      1
        ///      Any character
        ///      6
        ///  
        ///
        /// </summary>
        public static Regex regex = new Regex(
              "1.6",
            RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
            | RegexOptions.Compiled
            );


        // This is the replacement string
        public static string regexReplace =
              "hello";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = @"
116,
1e6
";
            string result = regex.Replace(input, regexReplace);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }


    }
```